# Get second between TIMESTAMP field and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp

I wand to know, seconds between to date-time

One of my field is `CreateDate(it's Timestamp)` and other is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(current date)`

So what I do is:

```
((CreateDate)- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Result_Seconds
```

But I got this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: A column of type `TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server has **absolutely NOTHING** to do with a date and time - it's just a binary counter

Comment: @marc_s so what's your suggest

Comment: I'm suggesting that you simply cannot determine seconds between a `TIMESTAMP` and a current date - since `TIMESTAMP` is ***NO*** date/time value.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `timestamp` as `datetime` and then use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(
                SECOND,
                CAST(Column1 as datetime),
                CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as datetime)
                ) Result_Seconds
FROM yourtable
```

Or as MSDN says about [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx):

> This function is the ANSI SQL equivalent to GETDATE.

So you can use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(
                SECOND,
                CAST(Column1 as datetime),
                GETDATE()
                ) Result_Seconds
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Having DATEDIFF is so mistake on sql project , because for big data it doesn't work

Comment: Is `2,147,483,647` seconds too small? Then use unix timestamp in seconds (bigint) and work with it. AFAIK in SQL Server 2016 they add datediff analog that returns bigint value.